# Font face - own font doesnt work in OPERA ,,unknown property"

Tags: fonts, font-face, opera

```
.title_font{
        font-family: montserrat;
        src: url("/assets/font/Montserrat-Light.otf") format("opentype");
}
  @font-face {
font-family: 'montserrat';
src: url('/assets/font/Montserrat-Light.otf') format("opentype");
font-weight: bold;
```

}

NEITHER OF THESE is working... can you help me ? It says Unknown property ... path to the font is good.

Comment: This first code is invalid, but the `@font-face` rule should work. "Unknown property" is usually indicative of a typo, can you create an online version with the original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional step one: convert your OTF to WOFF, because you want the browser to know that this is not just a generic system font, but one you *intended* to use online. WOFF parsing is not as strict as generic system font rules, and WOFF wrap ttf/otf sources byte for byte with optional zlib (WOFF)/brotli (WOFF2) compression, making the fonts significantly smaller over the wire.

Then, a not even remotely optional step two: you're defining this resource to *only* be used when the font family is `montserrat` **and** the weight is set to `bold` (or numerical value 700, which is the same thing in CSS). As such, your font resource does not apply when you leave off the weight, because that results in a weight that is `normal`/400, and so should clearly *not* map to the @font-face declaration you show.

If you want it to apply your font to any weight, remove that `font-weight` restriction in your `@font-face` declaration, or better yet: supply a proper list of which resource to use for which weight/style combination.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: montserrat;
  src: url(.../regular.woff) format("woff");
  style: normal;
  weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: montserrat;
  src: url(.../light.woff) format("woff");
  style: normal;
  weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: montserrat;
  src: url(.../bolditalic.woff) format("woff");
  style: italic;
  weight: bold;
}
```

and so on.